Can not edit Contact (user) photo image
I am able to add photo to contact.
But i am not able to change or delete contact photo.
This isa an error i am getting.
thank you
WordPress version 6.5.3
Current plugin: CiviCRM (version 5.72.1)
PHP version 8.1.16
Error Details
An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 1086 of the file /home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Contact.php. Error message: Uncaught TypeError: array_key_exists(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, null given in /home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Contact.php:1086

Not sure about the error message you pasted but there was an issue related to deleting a contact image which is fixed in recent version.
You can apply the patch or upgrade CiviCRM to 5.73.x
